# Can we say "LeBron James substituted" if he was substituted out?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, american-english, idiomatic-language

As far as I know, in sports, we can say someone substituted or he/she was substituted if he entered the game later in the game instead of another player. I wonder if native English speakers also can use a sentence like "LeBron James substituted" if he was substituted out of the game. Can we say these if the player was subbed out?

> LeBron James was substituted.

> LeBron James substituted.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/substitute), the verb **substitute** has different meanings depending on whether it is transitive or intransitive. This is clearly stated in the American English entry, and is covered by the separate **substitute for** entry for British English.

All of the following sentences are correct and describe the same situation:

> The manager substituted LeBron James for player X. -*transitive, active voice*
> LeBron was substituted for player X. - *transitive, passive voice*
> LeBron substituted for player X. - *intransitive, active voice*

In British English, the for-phrase is optional in the transitive version, but required for the intransitive version, unless you are talking about a substitute teacher: I don't know whether it can be omitted in American English.